# Is there a no-cost way to add sticky notes like "Adobe Acrobat"?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, sticky-notes

Is there a way to add sticky notes like "Adobe Acrobat"?

Sticky notes over text document, images etc. Specially I want to comment with balloon on big images.  Any solution must be no-cost.

[image: Adobe Acrobat document comment tool]

Answer (score 1):

Online: [PDFescape](http://www.pdfescape.com/open/?1087212) can do this

Offline: I'm fairly sure [PDF X-Change Viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer) has this functionality (though I can't test that right now)

Comment: I tried PDF X-Change Viewer. It doesn't work well with images. when I add images it shows at only 50% zoom